# Why does this file with dots and backslashes only show up with ls -lah and not ls?

Tags: linux, ls

I am removing a file which has been identified as infected. This file has dots and windows-style backslashes in the name. (Linux directories are separated with slashes like this "/" whereas this file contains slashes like this "\")

The actual file name is (note this is not a path, this entire string is the name):

```
..\lib\plugin\amd.dll
```

This pasted text shows me viewing that file with ls -lah (see line 4)

```
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 9.3K Aug 11  2014 host.frm
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql    0 Aug 11  2014 host.MYD
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 2.0K Aug 11  2014 host.MYI
-rw-rw-rw-  1 mysql mysql  40K Nov  9  2014 ..\lib\plugin\amd.dll
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 8.4K Feb  7  2015 lokfdh.frm
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 8.6K Aug 11  2014 ndb_binlog_index.frm
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql    0 Aug 11  2014 ndb_binlog_index.MYD
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1.0K Aug 11  2014 ndb_binlog_index.MYI
```

HOWEVER if I simply use "ls" alone, the file is not shown. See the below pasted text without the file. With "ls -lah" (shown above) the file appears right after "host.MYI" but with "ls" alone (shown below), the file does not appear at all.

```
host.frm
host.MYD
host.MYI
lokfdh.frm
ndb_binlog_index.frm
ndb_binlog_index.MYD
ndb_binlog_index.MYI
```

My question is, why do I need to use "ls -lah" to see it?  Why doesn't "ls" alone show it?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please cut-and-paste text into your question? Screenshots are both wasteful of storage, and cannot easily be indexed.  When graphics are involved, they may be unavoidable; but for text, this is not so.

Comment: Good point MadHatter! I will do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's specifically `-a` which makes a difference.

From ls(1):

```
   -a, --all
          do not ignore entries starting with .
```

Ie, normally filenames beginning with a dot (`.`) are considered "hidden" (often used for eg configuration files in a user's home directory).